# Checking validity on radio buttons in multi-page form

Tags: javascript, html, validation, radio-button

I've looked through several similar subjects but haven't found a solid answer to this issue.  I am trying to verify the value on my radio buttons so you cannot proceed to the next tab until one choice is selected.  This is just the MCVE of the code, the original page will have over 50 radio fields, so I would like to do this as generally as possible.  By modifying the validateForm function, I was trying to develop some sort of code that confirms the input type of the field, gets the name of that field then checks to see if that name has a value, I have experimented with using onclick="this.value = 'x'" so there wouldn't be a value until it is selected, though I have removed that for the sake of the mcve.  Not sure if this is possible, though I don't know why it wouldn't be, it seems plausible enough, though everything I've tried has failed.

Here is my MCVE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable:no"/></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/willowsystems/jSignature/master/libs/jSignature.min.js"></script>
<style>

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.tab {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}
</style>
<body>

<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="tab tab1"> 
  Location:
  <table id= "Address">
  <tr>
  <td>PDX</td>
  <td>EUG</td>
  <td>SEA</td>
  <td>SFO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="radio" id="PDX" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Address" value="PDX"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="EUG" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Address" value="EUG"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="SEA" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Address" value="SEA"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="SFO" oninput="this.className = ''" name="Address" value="SFO"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tab2">
  Driver Performing Inspection:
<p><input type="text" oninput="this.className = ''" name="drivername" placeholder="Your full name"></p>
  </div>
   <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.height = "100%";
  x[n].style.overflow = "visible";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.height = "0";
  x[currentTab].style.overflow = "hidden";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    $("regForm").submit(function(){renderSignature();saveImage();
    });
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      // If a field is empty...
   if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and a place to view the code in action:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8I5NEPXLJK5

Comment: Please edit your question and narrow down the code block to just the relevant lines of code.

Comment: I am not skilled enough to mess with the javascript too much, I've removed everything from the first posting that doesn't seem 100% relevant to me.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried adding this to the validateForm function: ```else if (y[i].type == "radio") {
    var z = y[i].name;
    var za = document.getElementByName(z);
     if (za.value == "") {
         y[i].className += " invalid";
         valid = false;      
      }
     }```  But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution.

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      // If a field is empty...
   if (y[i].value == "" && y[i].type !== "radio") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
    else if (y[i].type == "radio") {
    var z = y[i].name;
    var za = $('input[name="'+ z +'"]:checked').val();
    var zz = za.length;
    if (zz = null) {valid = false;}
   }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Might not be elegant, but it works.